MySQL Database Performance Decimated After Server Migration
I have a CRM that I've built over the past couple of years that has been working fine.  The database is MySQL, and the front end is a web interface.  This week, we 'upgraded' our hosting plan from a shared server to a cloud server, and immediately we saw a complete collapse of performance on some queries.  Routine searches that used to take under a second started taking several minutes and causing the site to crash.  I feel like the company is gaslighting me, telling me that it's an issue with needing to optimize my queries, and not addressing the fact that this drop in performance happened right after they moved our website and database to a different server.
Here is an example query that runs from one of our most frequently accessed pages.
SELECT A.ID, H.Member_Type, H.Member_Subtype, L.Current_Status AS Job_Status
FROM Member_ID A 
LEFT JOIN Member_ID_Status A2 ON A.First_Status = A2.ID 
LEFT JOIN Member_Name B ON A.MemberID = B.MemberID AND B.Current_Status = 'Active' AND B.Preferred = 'Yes' 
LEFT JOIN Member_Election_Districts ET ON A.MemberID = ET.MemberID 
LEFT JOIN Member_Addresses C ON A.MemberID = C.MemberID AND C.Current_Status = 'Active' AND C.Preferred = 'Yes' 
LEFT JOIN Member_Phones D ON A.MemberID = D.MemberID AND D.Current_Status = 'Active' AND D.Preferred = 'Yes' 
LEFT JOIN Member_Emails F ON A.MemberID = F.MemberID AND F.Current_Status = 'Active' AND F.Preferred = 'Yes' 
LEFT JOIN Member_Current_Parameters H ON A.MemberID = H.MemberID 
LEFT JOIN Member_SQ HH ON A.MemberID = HH.MemberID AND HH.SQID='0' AND HH.Current='Yes' 
LEFT JOIN Member_Language I ON A.MemberID = I.MemberID AND I.Current_Status = 'Active' AND I.Preferred = 'Yes' 
LEFT JOIN Member_Leaders J ON A.MemberID = J.MemberID AND J.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN COPE_ID K ON A.MemberID = K.MemberID AND K.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN Job_ID L ON A.MemberID = L.MemberID 
LEFT JOIN Job_Location MM ON L.JobID = MM.JobID AND MM.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN WS_Work_Area MMM ON MM.Worksite_Area = MMM.ID 
LEFT JOIN Job_Start_Date N ON L.JobID = N.JobID AND N.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN Job_Termination_Date NN ON L.JobID = NN.JobID AND NN.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN Job_Type O ON L.JobID = O.JobID AND O.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN Job_Classification P ON L.JobID = P.JobID AND P.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN Job_EmployeeID PP ON L.JobID = PP.JobID AND PP.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN Job_Wage PPP ON L.JobID = PPP.JobID AND PPP.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN Job_Employer_Division Q ON L.JobID = Q.JobID AND Q.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN Employer_List R on Q.EmpID = R.ID 
LEFT JOIN WS_Name S ON MM.WS_ID = S.WS_ID AND S.Current_Status = 'Active' AND S.Preferred = 'Yes' 
LEFT JOIN WS_Address T ON MM.WS_ID = T.WS_ID AND T.Current_Status = 'Active' AND T.Preferred = 'Yes' 
LEFT JOIN Job_Shift U ON L.JobID = U.JobID AND U.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN Job_Weekly_Hours WH ON L.JobID = WH.JobID AND WH.Current_Status = 'Active' 
LEFT JOIN Dues_Billing DB ON L.JobID = DB.JobID 
LEFT JOIN COPE_Billing CB ON L.JobID = CB.JobID 
LEFT JOIN Member_Early_Vote MEV ON A.MemberID = MEV.MemberID AND MEV.Election = '' 
LEFT JOIN Contracts_2_Emp_WS X ON Q.EmpID = X.EmpID AND Q.Division = X.Division AND MM.WS_ID = X.WS_ID AND X.Current_Status = 'Active' 
WHERE 1=1 
AND A.Current_Status = 'Active' 
AND Q.EmpID = '2' 
GROUP BY A.MemberID, L.JobID 
HAVING 1=1 AND Job_Status = 'Active';

and here is the EXPLAIN for this query.  It executes in 0.575 sec, in spite of joining about 30 tables together.

One of the returned columns on this query is H.Member_Type.  I already have a couple of WHERE conditions on the above query, but if I also add a WHERE condition on H.Member_Type (adding "AND H.Member_Type = 'Member" right before the 'GROUP BY statement), this query suddenly takes between 5 and 20 minutes to complete.  I should note that the column I'm adding the WHERE condition to in this second query is indexed.  Here is the EXPLAIN for this query.

Adding to the confusion for me, if I choose to add a WHERE condition to another column, something like 'First_Name' which is not an indexed value, the performance of the query is only a little bit slower.  (in that case, the query runs in about 2 seconds)
My database does have a lot of tables, and most of my queries do pull from several tables at once, but all join columns are indexed and joins are mostly 1:1, and we've never had performance issues before.  I also, for my login on our CRM, display query times on the screen, so every day I'm seeing query times on these types of searches, and the worse I'll see on a complex query with lots of conditions will maybe be 3 or 4 seconds, but simple queries like these never take more than a second.
I've tried rebuilding indexes on some of the tables that seemed to be causing problems.  That's had no noticeable impact so far.
I've been testing peeling away some of the joins from my query just to see if I can tell if any other specific tables are causing a problem.  If I pull a lot of the joins away I can eventually get a query to run quickly with the WHERE condition on Member_Type, but it's inconsistent.
I've mostly been fighting with our hosting company, as I'm convinced that they did something wrong in the migration, or that the server they moved us onto is the problem.  But even if the server was under resourced, it doesn't make sense to me that a query with identical joins would go from 0.5 seconds to over 17 minutes in the screenshot above, simply by adding a basic WHERE condition.  My problem is I don't know what the potential causes could be, so I don't know what to ask them to check, and they're acting like this is all just a matter of overly complex queries on my part.  I feel like I'm going insane.
ADDITIONAL INFO BASE ON COMMENTS/QUESTIONS
Sorry for burying some of these in the comments below, here is some additional info requested:
Both the old shared server and the new cloud server run MySQL 8.0, and they informed me that the MySQL configurations are unified and centrally managed, so there should have been no changes in MySQL configuration -- The shared server they are now telling me ran on 40 CPU cores with 72GB of RAM, and our cloud server has 4 cores and 8GB of RAM w/ 40GB of SSD space. I asked before migrating to make sure that I wouldn't see a slowdown and they told me that it would, in fact, be faster (apparently I shouldn't have taken their word for that!). Web server and DB server are on the same VM
The 'GROUP BY' does not reduce the resulting rows by much.  81 rows without the GROUP BY statement, 79 rows with.
The dataset should fit in the buffer pool without any problem - to highlight the issue here, I deliberately chose a query that was already narrowed down to a fairly small number of return rows.  Many other queries on our site are still working fine - ones returning many thousands of rows and which include a lot of nested queries and wildcard search criteria, etc.  We don't have tables with millions of records, we have one or two tables with a few hundred thousand records, but none of the tables involved in this query has over 50,000.

@MikeJohnson You have a unique constraint on MemberID and a separate
surrogate PK. Why did you not make MemberID the PK? Is this common to
many of the tables in this query? –  user1191247

It's not typical of most of my tables.  MemberID is the unique identifier for individuals, and all of our other tables can have multiple values associated with a single MemberID.  The Member_Current_Parameters table was created just to deal with Member Type.  Before I had that table, I'd do a subquery to find the most recent Member Type assigned in a separate Member_Type table, but that was inefficient for the query structure, so I created a separate table just to hold the current member type data so it could be a direct 1:1 join, and always seemed to work well. I still have the Member_Type table as well, as I have other queries that need to be able to determine what someone's member type was at any particular date in the past and we also need to track notes associated with any changes in member type, but that's all more than we need for basic queries of current data.  I could have made the MemberID the PK on this table, but it's not a PK on any other tables so for consistency, I always just have an autoincrement PK on every table.
UPDATE
I made some changes to my database structure and got this query working, but my underlying concerns still remain.
In my previous structure, each piece of job data exists in it's own table (wage, start date, etc.). This is to make it less costly to maintain a full history of updates and changes, adding a new value for a field only requires a few columns of data in a table, not duplicating all of the data for an entire job, and it also lets us store status update data relative to every change in information.  The main table that tracks jobs (Job_ID), just has the JobID # which is used to pull all of the relevant data for that job when we search for it.  The queries have always been very quick.
What I did now that I'm faced with the limitations of the new server, is I added another dozen columns to the Job_ID table to hold the current active values for all data relative to the job, and updated the related queries that are called for job updates to not only change the values in the individual tables, but also to update each piece of information on the relevant job in the Job_ID table as well.  I kinda hate it because it means I'm storing data in that table that also exists elsewhere, which feels like an unnecessary duplicate use of space, but it did get the problematic query down from 5+ minutes to 0.2 seconds, which is a win I guess.
What still makes me concerned is whether the reduce cores and RAM on the cloud server can explain the difference between running the original query I highlighted in under a second and taking >5 min when adding another specific WHERE condition? It seems like, if the new setup was going to be slower, it would be more universally slow, as opposed to running some queries fine, and then crashing on other specific ones.  So my concern is that maybe I've sidestepped an issue with my 'fix' here, but that issue is still there and could raise it's head again on another query/table/process?

With no details about your old or new hosting environments we can only guess at what might be the key differences. OS, MySQL version, buffer pool config, temp table config, types of storage, RAM specs, CPU specs, etc. Are the web server and DB server running on the same VM? Does the dataset fit in the buffer pool? Is DB server I/O or CPU bound while this query is running? What is the impact of moving Job_Status = 'Active' from the HAVING clause to the WHERE clause - L.Current_Status = 'Active'? How many rows are returned by this query before applying the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses?

Additional DB information request, please.   From your OLD and NEW deployed instance.
OS, Version?
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,   from your OLD and NEW servers - and this will require the assistance of your hosting company - unless you have access to the OS Command Prompt.
top -b -n 1  for most active apps,
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your threads memory / cpu usage,
ulimit -a       list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count,
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:,
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Please post from your NEW SERVER text results of SHOW CREATE TABLE member_current_parameters; for analysis.

Please also post THE QUERY used for the SECOND EXPLAIN so we have the details of QUERY submitted that takes 5-20 minutes to complete.

Mike, The comments from 7 minutes ago should confirm the NEW server will be SLOWER for any significant workload.  It is impossible to do the work of 40 CPU cores on 4 cores.  And that is not even mentioning chopping from 72 GB Ram to 8 GB.  Your NEW server does not have anywhere close to the resources of the old SHARED server.

Please view my profile.  And please get me any of the information requested by me in the past hour.  It will require the hosting organizations assistance to get the OS reports.

Wilson, the text outputs you suggested: (A) https://justpaste.it/ea5io  (B) https://justpaste.it/g4z4t  (C) https://justpaste.it/btpwo  (D) https://justpaste.it/cpz78  (E) https://justpaste.it/drlgb   The last one, SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS - says I don't have permission to run this operation.  Working on a few of the other asks and will post in another reply shortly, thank you for the feedback and suggestions...

Wilson, here is the full text of both queries  https://justpaste.it/d74x2  also in answer to another question on the queries, moving the job status condition to the WHERE clause did not help.  For some reason, moving the Member_Type condition to the HAVING clause did seem to help quite a bit, but not back to an acceptable performance as to be a solution.  Finally on the query questions, the grouping does not significantly reduce the number of rows, on this query it was 81 rows before grouping vs. 79 rows after.

Mike,  I take it you will not be able to get details from OLD server for comparison.
Please post from your NEW SERVER text results of SHOW CREATE TABLE member_current_parameters; for analysis.  Will check back here in the AM to see if any more data is available before starting workload analysis.  Thanks for postings you have been able to get.

Mike, The additional WHERE condition that caused minutes to be used can be minimized if you will post the SHOW  CREATE TABLE member_current_parameters; text results.  I will then be able to provide a suggestion to create an index that will get time to query completion minimized on your instance - even with only 4 cores and 8 GB ram.

Wilson, here is the output from the SHOW CREATE TABLE Member_Current_Parameters command: (https://justpaste.it/6hob6) - Thank you!

@MikeJohnson You have a unique constraint on MemberID and a separate surrogate PK. Why did you not make MemberID the PK? Is this common to many of the tables in this query?

It looks like all the tables except A, B, L, Q are unnecessary.  See if you can remove all the unused tables.  As shown by the EXPLAIN, MySQL will wast time looking at the them.

@MikeJohnson I am probably barking up the wrong tree here, but please try testing your queries after increasing the tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size to 128MB, instead of the current 32MB - SET @@SESSION.max_heap_table_size=134217728; SET @@SESSION.tmp_table_size=134217728;.

@user1191247 was definitely worth a shot, but it did not impact the query time.

Mike,
Please consider trying
ALTER TABLE Member_Current_Parameters ADD UNIQUE INDEX M_C_P_uncvi_M-M_Ty-M_Su (MemberID,Member_Type,Member_Subtype);
for Unique Covering Index to reduce time required complete the 5 minute query when WHERE was added.
If this works out, DROP INDEX memberid ON Member_Current_Parameters;
Not tested here.  Contact, if necessary, please.

Made the index change, and no impact on the query speed, still over 5 minutes.   And it's just so odd because it's always been the case that adding additional search criteria on indexed data fields has reduced the query time, not increased it.

Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN so we can see the index chosen by the optimizer. You may need to Force Index Use of the new index - and get in touch, please.

yes it's using the new index, EXPLAIN text for query here (https://justpaste.it/fygrf), I'll shoot you an email tomorrow as well, thank you.

Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE Member_ID;
